# Bold math in section headers with sffamily

Tags: fonts

I am using a header with `sffamily` as my font, as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Let $x^2=1$}

\end{document}
```

However, the `x=1` part in the header doesn't look nice, as it uses a much thinner font than the header. I tried changing it to `\mathbf{$x=1$}`, but it still doesn't look like nice as I am using `sffamily` as my font. Is there any way to make it look a bit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example generates an error but you can get bold math via

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Let $x=1$}
\section{Let $\mathsf{x=1}$}

\end{document}
```